# Which one is more efficient combining same styles into one class and using it or the other way around?

Tags: html, css, web-performance

### Which one of below code snippet will perform better?

**First Case**

```css
.a {
 color: #000;
 width: 20px;
 -webkit-transition: 0.3s all;
 -moz-transition: 0.3s all;
 -o-transition: 0.3s all;
 transition: 0.3s all;
}
.b {
 color: #333;
 width: 40px;
 -webkit-transition: 0.3s all;
 -moz-transition: 0.3s all;
 -o-transition: 0.3s all;
 transition: 0.3s all;
}
.c {
 color: #999;
 width: 90px;
 -webkit-transition: 0.3s all;
 -moz-transition: 0.3s all;
 -o-transition: 0.3s all;
 transition: 0.3s all;
}
```

```html
<div class="a"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="c"></div>
```

**Second Case**

```css
.a {
 color: #000;
 width: 20px;
}
.b {
 color: #333;
 width: 40px;
}
.c {
 color: #999;
 width: 90px;
}
.smooth {
 -webkit-transition: 0.3s all;
 -moz-transition: 0.3s all;
 -o-transition: 0.3s all;
 transition: 0.3s all;
}
```

```html
<div class="a smooth"></div>
<div class="b smooth"></div>
<div class="c smooth"></div>
```

In first case same styles are being used all across div while in other case same styles are grouped into one class and that class is added into divs.

which will perform better?

Comment: The performance difference is likely immeasurably insignificant. Maintainability and expressiveness should be your main concern.

Comment: I agree with deceze. Though the second case causes lower traffic. As well as being easier to use and maintain, `.smooth` is not limited to `.a .b .c`.

Comment: also, "Single Responsibility Principle"

Comment: You don't need to prefix those transition properties any more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In terms of performance the difference is not significant, however it is recommended to practice what is called DRY CSS.

If my memory is correct, DRY CSS is [a term coined by Jeremy Clarke](https://vimeo.com/38063798) about 4 years ago. DRY means "Don't Repeat Yourself" and as such **your second solution should be preferred**.

[Harry Roberts (csswizardry.com) explained](http://csswizardry.com/2013/07/writing-dryer-vanilla-css/) the two most important reasons why you would use DRY CSS:

> - Less actual code, meaning smaller file sizes, less for the user to have to download, more efficient code, etc.
> - Less to have to maintain; not repeating yourself means that you can make fewer changes to your codebase.

Comment: Agree but let's consider the situation where you have to optimize the first-byte time, in that case two points I have:

1. We can put required css for first-byte time synchronously and load rest asynchronously.

2. Less class in HTML document less the size of document, faster the load.

Comment: You are right, in the end what we are looking for is **to improve the final customer experience**. Inlining "above the fold" CSS and loading the rest asynchronously is one of the tool we have to make our website feels faster. There is a great talk about that subject by Tim Kadlec [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S8B7oYsjBtM). In theory your are right for your second point too, but the difference in terms of performance is meaningless. I would say the mehtodology to use depends on the type of project you have: will it be updated often? is there a big team working on the website?...